# Inserting a unique value in the set based on value's property

Tags: swift, set

I've created a struct with an "id" property:

```swift
struct SomeStruct: Hashable {
    let id: String; // should be unique
    let date: String;
    let comment: String;
    
    static func ==(lhs: SomeStruct, rhs: SomeStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

I need to insert these structs in a set, but the set itself should decide whether the new member is unique or not based on its id, so:

```swift
someSet.insert(SomeStruct(id: "1", date: "22.09.2022", comment: "nothing here")) //inserted: true
someSet.insert(SomeStruct(id: "1", date: "05.12.1978", comment: "something here!")) //inserted: false, not unique id
```

That is why I implement the equality operator func in the struct and sometimes it works... but sometimes it doesn't and here I am, humbly asking for your help.
My implementation gives me weird results. The structs with the same id's can both be inserted or not, for example if I build my playground file once and new value gets inserted, next time I build it and the same value returns false.
I may have missed something, maybe I should implement custom hashValue property..?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. My job is to create a collection of these structs, where each struct has unique id. If you did it before and/or you think you know how to do it better, please let me know, I will be very glad to hear your ideas.

Comment: You need to also override the hash(into:) function to match

Comment: @Alexander can you please give me a hint how to do that and not to run into hash conflict?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because `Set` uses the hash value to find/store elements, falling back on `Equatable` only when hash values are equal to determine if the elements are really equal or if it's a hash collision.  `Dictionary` keyed on the `id` seems a better fit.  Does it not fit your case for some reason?

Comment: @ChipJarred yes, dictionary could be a good solution, thanks! But I do want to understand how to implement this mechanism based on set.

Comment: @IvanB Just implement your own has method. `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { hasher.combine(id) }`

Comment: @LeoDabus works like a charm! So it basically assigns hash value of id string to hash value of the whole struct?

Comment: @IvanB `Set` is implemented as a hash table.   Last I looked it used linear probing as the technique for handling hash collisions.  So it uses elements hash value to find a storage location in the table.  If there's something already there, it checks if they are equal, then linearly searches the table (wrapping to the start), either looking for an equal element, or an empty place to insert.  It's a pretty standard hash table implementation, so just look up how hash tables works, and you'll know how `Set` works.

Comment: Yes if you don't implement your own hash method it would be based on all properties and that's not what you want

Comment: @LeoDabus's fix works great if you only  need `SomeStruct` to be hashable-distinct on `id`, which his the case for your stated use case, but if you're putting it some other data structures that depend all of its properties for their hashes, you'll break those.

Comment: @ChipJarred well that's what OP needs. Unique ID.

Comment: @LeoDabus, indeed that is the stated problem, and it's a perfectly good solution for it.  I didn't mean to seem critical of that.  I was just warning of possible consequences, since the question is undoubtedly just a slice of a larger program.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was given in comments, which was to hash only on `id` instead of relying on the compiler generated implementation, which hashes on all the properties.  That solution is a perfectly valid one for the stated problem, and may be ideal for your use case.

It does have one potential drawback:  It means `SomeStruct` is only ever hashably-distinct based on `id`.  That is the case that's presented, but we don't see the wider code base (nor should we).  Is `SomeStruct` only ever used so that having its hash value based solely on its `id` is the right thing?  It definitely could be, and probably is, since most things with a unique ID work that way, but it doesn't have to be, and I don't like making that assumption about code I can't see.

A more code-base agnostic and reusable approach is rather than tweaking the data's implementation to make a given collection behave the way you want, you can make a collection with that desired behavior for the data you have.  There's more code involved in this approach, but it also gives more flexibility in how you can use the data.

The described behavior is that of a `Dictionary` keyed on the `id`, but the API of `Set`.  There are some options.  Here's one.

First make `SomeStruct` conform to `Identifiable` which is a standard Swift protocol.  All that means is that it needs a `Hashable` `id` property, which you already have so adding that conformance is just:

```swift
extension SomeStruct: Identifiable { }
```

Though you could add `Identifiable` to the definition of `SomeStruct` instead.  Either way works.

Then create a data structure that is keyed on `id`.  This doesn't have to be complicated.  Just leverage the existing thing that does most of what you need to implement it.  In this case, that's `Dictionary`.  So here's a minimal, but generic, `IDSet` that does that:

```swift
struct IDSet<T: Identifiable>
{
    public   typealias Element = T
    internal typealias Storage = [Element.ID: Element]

    private var storage = Storage()

    public mutating func insert(_ value: Element) -> Bool
    {
        guard !storage.keys.contains(value.id) else { return false }

        storage[value.id] = value
        return true
    }
}
```

Because `IDSet` is generic, you can make one for any kind of `Identifiable` thing.  It also doesn't need for the whole element to be `Hashable`.  It only needs its `id` to be `Hashable`.  That gives you more flexibility in the kinds of elements you store in it.

Presumably you'd want to iterate over the elements, so you'd need to make it conform to `Sequence`.  Again there's no need to get complicated in making an `Iterator`, because you can leverage `Dictionary`'s `Iterator`:

```swift
extension IDSet: Sequence
{
    public struct Iterator: IteratorProtocol
    {
        internal var iter: Storage.Iterator
        
        public mutating func next() -> Element?
        {
           guard let (_, value) = iter.next() else { return nil }
           return value
        }
    }

    public func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        Iterator(iter: storage.makeIterator())
    }
}
```

You probably want `IDSet` to conform to some other protocols too, but I think it's likely you can see how that would work.

To use it, it's much like `Set`, although `insert` returns a non-discardable `Bool` indicating whether the element was inserted.  Let's say you want to test this behavior in XCTest using your example data:

```swift
var someSet = IDSet<SomeStruct>()

XCTAssertTrue(someSet.insert(SomeStruct(id: "1", date: "22.09.2022", comment: "nothing here")))
XCTAssertFalse(someSet.insert(SomeStruct(id: "1", date: "05.12.1978", comment: "something here!")))
```

And of course, because it conforms to `Sequence` you can iterate over it:

```swift
for s in someSet {
    print("id: \(s.id), date: \(s.date), comment: \"\(s.comment)\"")
}
```

Or use various other `Sequence` methods:

```swift
let comments = someSet.map { $0.comment }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set) elements are [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable)

> Hashing a value means feeding its essential components into a hash function, represented by the Hasher type. Essential components are those that contribute to the type’s implementation of Equatable. Two instances that are equal must feed the same values to Hasher in hash(into:), in the same order.

I suggest adding:

```swift
struct SomeStruct: Hashable {
    let id: String;
    let date: String;
    let comment: String;
    
    static func ==(lhs: SomeStruct, rhs: SomeStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // feed the only property that contribute to Equatable implementation
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```